# Una division usando ArrayList

Tags: java, poo, estructuras-de-datos, arraylist, matemáticas

**Ejercicio:** Utilizando `ArrayList` elabore un programa que divida 2 numeros muy grandes (dígitos mayores a 10).

Ya 'resolví' el ejercicio pero no ocupe `ArrayList` porque no se me ocurrió cómo aplicarlo. No se como. Podrian darme alguna sugerencia? por favor?

```
public class Main {

    static void division(List<Integer> lista, List<Integer> listb) {

        List<Integer> listResult = new ArrayList<>();

        if (lista.size() <= 10 || listb.size() <= 10) {
            System.out.println("Los numeros deben ser mayores a 10");
        } else {double a = 0, j = 0;
            String Stringnumber = "";
            String Stringnumber2 = "";

            for (int number : lista) {
                Stringnumber += String.valueOf(number);
            }

            for (int number : listb) {
                Stringnumber2 += String.valueOf(number);
            }

            double test = Double.parseDouble(Stringnumber2);
            double test2 = Double.parseDouble(Stringnumber);

            double dividend = 0, divisor = 0;

            if (test >= test2) {
                dividend = test;
                divisor = test2;
            } else {
                dividend = test2;
                divisor = test;
            }

            for (int i = 9; i > 0 && j != 1; i--) {
                if (i * divisor <= dividend) {
                    listResult.add(i);

                    a = dividend - (i * divisor);
                    if (a >= divisor) {
                        i = 9;
                    } else {
                        j = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("El resultado es:");
            for (int i = 0; i < listResult.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(listResult.get(i));
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> listb = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("De un numero");
        for (char digit : x.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
            lista.add(digit - '0');
        }

        System.out.println("De otro numero");
        for (char digit : x.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
            listb.add(digit - '0');
        }
        x.nextLine();

        division(lista, listb);
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Porqué dices que no utilizas ArrayList si los objetos lista, listb y listResult son ArrayList? Otra cosa, no queda muy claro lo que se quiere hacer. ¿Utilizar ArrayList para introducir sólo un elemento en cada uno?

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Usar `Arraylist` para implementar la division. Podria ser eso, introducir sólo un elemento en cada uno, o bien introducir todos los elementos en una sola vez

Comment: El problema principal es que estás juntando los dígitos del número contenido en la lista y convirtiendo eso en un `double`. Eso está **mal**. La idea del ejercicio es que planteen una implementación similar a la que provee Java mediante la clase `BigDecimal`. Yo en lo personal, crearía una clase `NumeroGrande` que dentro tenga definido la lista para almacenar el número y, como implementación básica, tendría la resta de 2 números y luego la división es la resta consecutiva de números hasta tener un residuo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ 'La idea del ejercicio es que planteen una implementación similar a la que provee Java mediante la clase `BigDecimal`' y como porque estas tan seguro de eso? .Estaba yo pensando en este ejercicio y creo que una buena alternativa sería usando pilas y colas, algo asi como la evaluación de expresiones en forma polaca, seria como un caso particular: la división.El ejercicio pide usar ArrayList pero un ArrayList puede comportarse como pila o cola, o no?

Comment: Sí, puedes implementar el algoritmo que te ayude a resolver la división. Y sí, puedes hacer que un `ArrayList` simule ser una pila o cola, lo que más te ayude. Pero si vas a usar el `ArrayList` o cualquier otra colección solo para almacenar dígitos y luego crear un `double` a partir de eso, creo que la implementación no cumple con lo que necesitas. Por ejemplo, tu programa, pienso yo, debería resolver algo como `division("1234567890987654321234567890", "9182736450192");`

Comment: Otro ejemplo (que no se puede convertir a `double`): `division("1234567890987654321234567890123829837890129380293809840342310923102983012830192830198301928307498237498237498274928374927492873492734982734902984024312345678909876543212345678901238298378901293802938098403423109231029830128301928301983019283074982374982374982749283749274928734927349827349018809430403929849872.0", "2");`

Comment: aah y porque no lo resuelves mejor.. para tener un mejor entendimiento :D @LuiggiMendozaJ

Answer (score 1):

Si no es obligatorio que utilices Arrays yo haría algo así.

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;

        pedirNumeros(num1, num2);       

    }


    public static void pedirNumeros(double num1, double num2){
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);     
        float resultado;

        System.out.println("De un primer numero mayor a 10 cifras");
        num1 = x.nextDouble();
        while(num1/1000000000 < 1){
            System.out.println("No es correcto: De un numero mayor a 10 cifras");
            num1 = x.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.println("De un segundo numero mayor a 10 cifras");
        num2 = x.nextDouble();
        while(num2/1000000000 < 1){
            System.out.println("No es correcto: De un numero mayor a 10 cifras");
            num2 = x.nextDouble();
        }  

        resultado = dividir(num1, num2);
        System.out.println("El resultado es: " + resultado);
    }

    public static float dividir(double num1, double num2){
        if(num1 > num2){
            return (float)(num1/num2);
        }else{
            return (float)(num2/num1);  
        }
    }

}
```

O algo similar utilizando un Array:

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        pedirNumeros();          

    }


    public static void pedirNumeros(){
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);     
        List<Double> listaNumeros = new ArrayList<>();
        float resultado;

        System.out.println("De un primer numero mayor a 10 cifras");
        listaNumeros.add(0, x.nextDouble());
        while(listaNumeros.get(0)/1000000000 < 1){
            System.out.println("No es correcto: De un numero mayor a 10 cifras");
            listaNumeros.add(0, x.nextDouble());
        }

        System.out.println("De un segundo numero mayor a 10 cifras");
        listaNumeros.add(1, x.nextDouble());
        while(listaNumeros.get(1)/1000000000 < 1){
            System.out.println("No es correcto: De un numero mayor a 10 cifras");
            listaNumeros.add(1, x.nextDouble());
        }  

        resultado = dividir(listaNumeros);
        System.out.println("El resultado es: " + resultado);
    }

    public static float dividir(List<Double> listaNumeros){
        if(listaNumeros.get(0) > listaNumeros.get(1)){
            return (float)(listaNumeros.get(0)/listaNumeros.get(1));
        }else{
            return (float)(listaNumeros.get(1)/listaNumeros.get(0));    
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Imagino que la primera idea del ejercicio es no convertir el número a `double` o `float`, sino más bien simular algo como `BigDecimal`.

Comment: De ser asi deberia cambiar la pregunta